# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\frac{3\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}+1}$ Diverge or Converge?

Tags: summation, absolute-convergence

Does the following summation converge or diverge?
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\frac{3\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}+1}.\tag{1}
\end{align}
I don't know where to begin. I think I should, however, use the absolute value test s. th. if
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\frac{3\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}+1}\right|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}+1}=3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}+1}\tag{2}
\end{align}
converges then $\left(1\right)$ converges. If I pick arbitrarily large values of $n$ then it seems $\left(2\right)$ does not get smaller and eventually $\rightarrow 0$.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: THe $n$-th term doesn't go to $0$.

Comment: Unless you intended that to be a cubic root.

Comment: @bd1251252 What do you think...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [term test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test). Since $$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=3,$$
then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{3\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}+1}=3$$
does not exist because it jumps between $3$ and $-3$. So the series does not converge.

Comment: Don't worry, just waiting for the time limit to run out so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt{n+1}\over\sqrt n +1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt{1+1/n}\over1+1/\sqrt n}=1.$$

Hence 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{n+1}{3\sqrt{n+1}\over\sqrt n + 1}$$
does not exist, and the series diverges.